# Как отправить запрос с конкретной формы и передать ID или Class формы в PHP-скрипт через ajax-запрос?

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 одинаковые формы:

Первая с id="form1" и классом "js-form1":

```
<form id="form1" class="contact_form js-form1" action="#">
    <h4 class="form_title">Контакты</h4>
    <div class="fields_wrapper">
        <input class="field name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия Имя" required>
        <input class="field email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input class="field phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" required>
        <textarea class="field message" name="message" placeholder="Суть вопроса" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Вторая с id="form2" и классом "js-form2":

```
<form id="form2" class="contact_form js-form2" action="#">
    <h4 class="form_title">Контакты</h4>
    <div class="fields_wrapper">
        <input class="field name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия Имя" required>
        <input class="field email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input class="field phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" required>
        <textarea class="field message" name="message" placeholder="Суть вопроса" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Также есть js-функция отправки формы:

```
function sendForm(form) {

    var data = {
        name: $(form).find("input[name='name']").val(),
        phone: $(form).find("input[name='phone']").val(),
        question: $(form).find("textarea[name='question']").val(),
        button: $(form).find("input[name='button']").val(),
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/send.php",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            alert("Отправлено!");
        }
    });

}
```

Как нужно вызывать js-функцию, чтобы она брала данные с той формы которую отправили? И как передать через ajax или ID, или Class формы? В зависимости от формы нужно в PHP-скрипте менять тему письма.

Comment: Можете получить ID атрибут при помощи jQuery `$(form).attr('id')` и потом отправить так же как и все остальное.

Comment: `Как нужно вызывать js-функцию` -- а как Вы ее сейчас вызываете? Наверное же должен быть какой-то обработчик `submit` события.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как нужно вызывать js-функцию, чтобы она брала данные с той формы которую отправили? И как передать через ajax или ID, или Class формы?

Такое можно реализовать, например вот так.

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const id = e.target.id
  alert('ИД формы ' + id)
  // тут можешь запускать свою функцию
})
```

```html
<h1>Первая с id="form1" и классом "js-form1"</h1>

<form id="form1" class="contact_form js-form1" action="#">
  <h4 class="form_title">Контакты</h4>
  <div class="fields_wrapper">
    <input class="field name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия Имя" required>
    <input class="field email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input class="field phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" required>
    <textarea class="field message" name="message" placeholder="Суть вопроса" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Отправить</button>
</form>

<h1>Вторая с id="form2" и классом "js-form2"</h1>

<form id="form2" class="contact_form js-form2" action="#">
  <h4 class="form_title">Контакты</h4>
  <div class="fields_wrapper">
    <input class="field name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия Имя" required>
    <input class="field email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input class="field phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" required>
    <textarea class="field message" name="message" placeholder="Суть вопроса" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
```